# failed with strange response when using chkconfig

Tags: bash

I was merely trying to add login.sh to startup so that my program MentoHust would run when i start my computer.login.sh is rather simple:

```
#! /bin/sh

sudo mentohust << "********"
```

I ran `sudo chkconfig --add login.sh`

Then I got this long response.

```
jacos@Jing:/etc/init.d$ sudo chkconfig --add login.sh
insserv: warning: script 'K01acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'login.sh' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'console-setup' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `console-setup'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `console-setup'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udevtrigger' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udevtrigger'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udevtrigger'
insserv: warning: script 'acpi-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-upstart-bridge' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-upstart-bridge'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-upstart-bridge'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udev' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udev'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udev'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'modemmanager' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `modemmanager'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `modemmanager'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'binfmt-support' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `binfmt-support'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'alsa-restore' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `alsa-restore'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `alsa-restore'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'atd' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `atd'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `atd'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'dmesg' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `dmesg'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `dmesg'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'cups' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cups'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cups'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'lightdm' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `lightdm'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `lightdm'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udevmonitor' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udevmonitor'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udevmonitor'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'module-init-tools' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `module-init-tools'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `module-init-tools'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'cron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `cron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `cron'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'acpid' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `acpid'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `acpid'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'avahi-daemon' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `avahi-daemon'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `avahi-daemon'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'alsa-store' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `alsa-store'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `alsa-store'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'anacron' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `anacron'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `anacron'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-interface-security' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `network-interface-security'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `network-interface-security'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hostname' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `hostname'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `hostname'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-stop' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-stop'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-stop'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'ufw' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `ufw'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `ufw'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'setvtrgb' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `setvtrgb'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `setvtrgb'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-manager' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `network-manager'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `network-manager'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'irqbalance' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `irqbalance'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `irqbalance'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udev-finish' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udev-finish'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udev-finish'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'friendly-recovery' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `friendly-recovery'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'udev-fallback-graphics' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `udev-fallback-graphics'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `udev-fallback-graphics'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-splash' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-splash'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-splash'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'mysql' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `mysql'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `mysql'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hwclock' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `hwclock'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `hwclock'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'network-interface' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `network-interface'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `network-interface'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'hwclock-save' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `hwclock-save'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `hwclock-save'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'dbus' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `dbus'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `dbus'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'procps' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `procps'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `procps'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'apport' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `apport'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `apport'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'gdm' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `gdm'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `gdm'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'rsyslog' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `rsyslog'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `rsyslog'
The script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an Upstart
job, but lsb-header is not supported for Upstart jobs.
insserv: warning: script 'plymouth-log' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: Default-Start undefined, assuming empty start runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-log'
insserv: Default-Stop  undefined, assuming empty stop  runlevel(s) for script `plymouth-log'
login.sh                  0:off  1:off  2:on   3:on   4:on   5:on   6:off
```

I don't understand much.All this LSB and header seems nothing to do with what i am doing at all...And the last line with numbers and `on`,`off` confused me farther.

Glad if you can explain this to me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initscripts must have a specific structure; see `/usr/share/doc/initscripts-*/sysvinitfiles` for details. If you only need to run a command or two then you can probably get away with just putting them in `/etc/rc.local` instead.

Comment: Despite the error output,it worked.Thanks,i will check that out.

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems with chkconfig setting on/on.
They went away by following advice on this thread by patching /lib/init/upstart-job:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/insserv/+bug/467000